# Searching an immutable JS Map

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Can you please suggest the most efficient way to search Immutable.Map's values?   I'm looking to return the first match.

https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

I believe I should get a `map.valueSeq()` and go from there.  I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Immutable= require("immutable")
var keys = Immutable.Map()
k=keys.set(1,2)
var result = null
k.valueSeq().map(
    function(value) {
        if(value == 2)
            result = value
    }
)
return result
```

I would like to stick with the Map data structure, it is used elsewhere in the code.

Comment: What exactly are you searching for? If you have the value, why do you need to look it up? Or do you want to look up values by key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.find`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/find):

```
var Immutable = require("immutable");
var map = Immutable.Map();
var m = map.set(1,2);
return m.find(function(val) {
    return val === 2;
});
```

You can use `m.valueSeq().find` as well.

Comment: The return should actually read as
        return m.find(function(val) {
            return val === 2;
        });

Comment: @BenBud Good catch! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Immutable.Map.Find

Example

```
var map = Immutable.Map()
map = map.set(1,2) //set or add data to map
var criteria=2;
var finded=map.find(function(data,key) {
    return data===criteria;//return the first value of data that return true
}, null);//return null if not found data
```

See on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fyr5nk4x/

Comment: This does not seem to work unfortunately. It looks like you cannot set a default value with `.find()`?